# Playing audio streams on a web page

Tags: java, flash, audio, applet, audio-streaming

I have a list of radio stations, mostly .mp3 and .ogg. I would like to have a player on a web page that could be controlled with JavaScript. Now I use [jlgui](http://www.javazoom.net/applets/jlguiapplet/jlguiapplet.html), but it is somewhat limited.

Do you know of any alternative to jlgui? Preferably a java applet, but I can tolerate flash or even a system-default media player for a particular content-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found JPlayer which uses HTML5 if available, otherwise it falls back to Flash. Works almost as good as the JLgui

Answer (score 1):

There are a thousand MP3 players for Flash, using the native streaming stuff. Unfortunately that copes generally poorly with streamed MP3 (either over Icecast HTTP, or even more so under SHOUTcast ICY). Generally the player has to reconnect to the stream every so often, causing a playback glitch, otherwise memory just fills with MP3 data.

OGG is harder. There's no native support, but in Flash 10 you can play any old samples you can decode yourself, so it's possible to implement your own OGG decoder. It needs a lot of CPU on the client though. See http://barelyfocused.net/blog/2008/10/03/flash-vorbis-player/ — I don't know of anyone having fixed this up into a single player that can do both MP3 and OGG from the same interface yet, but there's no reason it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: well the jlgui does work with both mp3 and ogg but it is in java and crashes often and takes ff with it. I have a copy online at cvek.si/RWindow.php

Comment: Yeah, I was just covering the Flash side of things as I've not touched applets for some years now. I would guess jlgui is having similar performance problems to the Flash ones. Does the simple JOrbisPlayer work for you? See http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/ under “Live Sreams in Ogg Vorbis”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JMF I guess:
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework)

[JMF Applet](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/guide/JMFApp-Applet.html)

Comment: I don't think JMF has support for ogg.